# Unknown processing time of SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this

```
SELECT 
    a.LeaseNo, RIGHT(a.LeaseNo, 1) AS idx 
FROM 
    Leases a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DebitNoteItems b ON a.leaseno = b.LeaseNo 
WHERE 
    status = 'A' 
    AND PortfolioType = 'R'  
    AND b.NoteItemID IS NULL
```

Result set is found in less than 1 second.

Then I tried to do find the records with idx = 0, thus I wrote

```
SELECT LeaseNo 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         a.LeaseNo, RIGHT(a.LeaseNo, 1) AS idx 
     FROM 
         Leases a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         DebitNoteItems b ON a.leaseno = b.LeaseNo 
     WHERE 
         status = 'A' 
         AND PortfolioType = 'R'  
        AND b.NoteItemID IS NULL) tmp 
WHERE
    tmp.idx = '0'
```

However, this query is very slow.

Then I tried

```
SELECT LeaseNo 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         a.LeaseNo, RIGHT(a.LeaseNo, 1) AS idx 
     FROM 
         Leases a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         DebitNoteItems b ON a.leaseno = b.LeaseNo 
     WHERE 
         status = 'A' 
         AND PortfolioType = 'R'  
        AND b.NoteItemID IS NULL) tmp 
WHERE
    tmp.idx LIKE '%0%'
```

This one is executed in less than 1 second.

I want to know why could the second one much faster than the first one when there are only 1 simple condition different (`= '0'` and `LIKE '%0%'`)? What am I talking about is not few seconds difference, by querying it and the differences are less than 1 second for the second query (applied LIKE), and more than a minute (applied =, in fact it is still querying, it is terminated manually, it doesn't look like it is comparing the idx in the queried tmp table)

Is there something wrong or inappropriate in the query?

Comment: I believe equals can use the indexes whereas like must check every row for a match.

Comment: Check the query plans (CTRL-L)

Comment: i do not have permission for the query plan